# Minimum and Maximum Resistance

Tags: optimization, physics

Given n resistors with resistance $R_1, R_2, \ldots, R_n$, and we can connect them with wires arbitrarily (this statement is not rigorous, but I think you understand what I mean), what is the minimum and maximum effective resistance?

It's folklore that the minimum (which is $R_1\|R_2\|\cdots\|R_n$) is got when the resistors are connected in parallel and the maximum (which is $R_1+R_2+\cdots+R_n$) is got when the resistors are connected in series, but I do not see a way to prove this. I searched and only found that this result is used without proof.

Comment: What do you mean be effective resistance?

Comment: If you use induction, the proof follows immediately. Fix 1 resistor, and consider if it's in series or parallel with the rest (in some combination).

Comment: @CalvinLin: You need to consider all connected graphs, its not clear (to me, that is) how to use induction on a graph (for this particular example)?

Comment: There are so many more interesting questions one could ask about such networks. For example, what is the computational complexity of finding the minimal/maximal resistance between points of such networks or to find said point pairs? How can you build a fault-tolerant resistor network? Etc.

Comment: As for induction, you can do induction on the number of vertices in the graph or you can use structural induction or well-founded induction.

Comment: It is unclear to me how to use the number of vertices as a basis for induction in a meaningful way. (This is not a question about understanding induction.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a well-known theorem about electrical networks called **Rayleigh's Monotonicity Theorem**:

**Theorem.** *Increasing the resistance of one resistor in a network cannot decrease the effective resistance of the network.*

See [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.0027) for a combinatorial proof of this theorem.  This has some basic corollaries:

**Corollary.** *Removing a resistor from a network cannot decrease the resistance.*
*Proof:* Removing a resistor is equivalent to increasing the resistance of the resistor to infinity. $\square$

**Corollary.** *Replacing a resistor by a short cannot increase the resistance.*
*Proof:* Replacing a resistor by a short is equivalent to decreasing the resistance of the resistor to zero. $\square$

We can use these corollaries to prove the minimum and maximum results you mentioned.

**The Maximum Result**

Given a network with resistors of resistances $R_1,\ldots,R_n$, choose a path from the initial vertex to the terminal vertex, and remove all of the resistors not on the path.  This does not decrease the resistance, and the resulting network is a simple series network involving *some* of the initial resistors.  In particular, the resulting network has resistance at most $R_1+\cdots + R_n$.

**The Minimum Result**

Given a network with resistors of resistances $R_1,\ldots,R_n$, choose a minimal [cut set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_set), i.e. a minimal set of resistors whose removal disconnects the initial vertex from the terminal vertex.  Replace all resistors that are not in this cut set by shorts.  This does not increase the resistance, and the result network is a simple parallel network involving *some* of the initial resistors.  In particular, the resulting network has resistance at least $R_1 \parallel \cdots \parallel R_n$

Comment: +1 Nice. I had hoped the result would follow from some simple manipulation of positive definite matrices :-).